# Getting decimals in itextsharp pdf file

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

I have been exporting DataGridView in iTextsharp, however the generated PDF file does not show the decimals which is visible on the win form.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[4].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";

PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cell.Value.ToString(), fontTitle));
                    cell3.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
                    pdfTable.AddCell(cell3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use cell.FormatedValue instead of cell.Value. cell.value is the raw data.